# PHP Session Variable Empty when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, session-variables

I'm trying to make a simple shopping cart that stores the cart items in a session variable and maintains the items that were in the cart even if the user refreshes the page or closes the tab and revisits the website on another tab. Whenever the user clicks an "Add to Cart" button, an AJAX Post request is fired to a php file which adds the product info to a session variable. However, when I refresh the page and try to display that session variable on the main index.php page, the variable is empty. I also have `session_start();` at the beginning of each file.

PHP file where AJAX Post request is made:

```
<?php
session_start();

$product = NULL;
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

if ($contentType === "application/json") {
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $product = json_decode($content, true);
}

if(is_array($product)) {
    $_SESSION["cart"] = $product["name"];
    echo json_encode(['cartinfo' => $_SESSION["cart"]]); //I console log this JSON response in the javascript file and see product info successfully
}
```

Main index.php page:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION["cart"]; //This is empty
```

Javascript:

```
function add() {
  fetch("scripts/product.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "name": "Shirt"
    })
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(jsonRes) {
    console.log(jsonRes);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); 
  });
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: It would be nice to see javascript code you use to do a call to backend.

Comment: @DmytroZasiadko Hi, I updated the question with the javascript

Comment: Double check URL, probably slash is missing in the beginning. Make sure you send session cookie to server, try to add 'credentials: "same-origin"' to request config object. And check what is in the server response.

Comment: @DmytroZasiadko Thank you!!!!! I added `credentials: "same-origin"` to the javascript right above `headers:` and now it's working